# How to auto close HostWebDialog box?

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, modal-dialog

I have ribbon button that open a dialog box. The thing is that when you click the ribbon button the dialog box should only flash and then close and refresh. I want to to it with javascript

I use this to get the dialog to show

```
HostWebDialog="TRUE"
HostWebDialogWidth="500"
HostWebDialogHeight="250"
```

And this to close with a button on the dialog box

```
window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*');
```

So how to auto close?

**EDIT**

Tried this but it didn't close I'm doing something wrong?

```
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(setTimeout(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*') }, 2000), function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
```

**EDIT2**

All my code:

```
'use strict';

var clientContext, hostweburl, parentContext, parentWeb, selectedItems, itemIds, listId;

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
listId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListId"));
itemIds = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListItemId")).split(',');
parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
parentWeb = parentContext.get_web();
selectedItems = parentWeb.get_lists().getById(listId).getItemById(itemIds);

function itemLoop() {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < itemIds.length; i++) {
    selectedItems = parentWeb.get_lists().getById(listId).getItemById(itemIds[i]);
    selectedItems.set_item('Status', 'Completed');
    selectedItems.set_item('PercentComplete', '1');
    selectedItems.update();
    clientContext.load(selectedItems);

}
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*'); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });


}

$(document).ready(function () {

});

function OnFail() {
alert("Error");
}
```

It wont auto close

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap you closing code in a `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function{
   window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*');
}, 2000);
```

The number 2000 indicates the number of milliseconds before the function will be executed

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

**Edit**

In your case, it seems you want to close when you have successfully executed a query?
If so, do something like this, no need for a `setTimeout`:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
        window.parent.postMessage('CloseCustomActionDialogRefresh', '*');
    },
    function (sender, args) { 
        alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); 
    }
);
```

Comment: yes when it has successfully executed a query but it dont auto close with that code and it's the auto close i need

Comment: That should auto close it (given that the code you provided as close-code actually works on its own, and that the executeQuery is successful

Comment: Ok weird it dosen't close anyway posted a pic do you know any other way to auto close it and the executeQuery is successful